# How to change shape color in Visio 2007

Tags: microsoft-visio

I'm trying to change the Firewall shape's color from orange to something else.  It's part of the built-in Networks and Peripherals library and while I can right-click > Format > Fill and change the color (and border, etc.) it doesn't actually have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up exporting it as an image and editing it in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Firewall master-shape include few sub-shapes
[image: Sub-shapes in Master Explorer]
Some sub-shapes have protected cells in their ShapeSheet™
[image: Protected cell in FillFormat Section of ShapeSheet]
you can manually change these two cells for each marked sub-shapes. Or use this simple macro

> Sub s() 
>      Dim mst As Shape, ssh As Shape
>      Set mst = ActiveDocument.Masters("Firewall").Shapes(1)
>      For Each ssh In mst.Shapes
>          ssh.Cells("FillForegnd").FormulaForce = 13
>          ssh.Cells("FillBkgnd").FormulaForce = 13
>      Next
>      End Sub

After this changes you can change colour of that shapes with Themes  [image: Apply themes]